# Warning in max(max_DOUBLE_ZERO_BID_PRICE, na.rm = T): no non-missing arguments ## to max; returning -Inf ERROR in R

Tags: r, arguments, warnings

When running code below I got lots of messages like:

```r
> ## Warning in max(max_DOUBLE_ZERO_BID_PRICE, na.rm = T): no non-missing arguments
> ## to max; returning -Inf
```

```r
sp500_options[order(STRIKEPRICE), lag_BID_PRICE := shift(BID_PRICE, n =1, type = "lag"), by = .(UNDERLYING, Time, MATURITYDATE, OPTIONTYPE)]

sp500_options[lag_BID_PRICE == 0 & BID_PRICE == 0, min_DOUBLE_ZERO_BID_PRICE := min(STRIKEPRICE), by = .(UNDERLYING, Time, MATURITYDATE, OPTIONTYPE)]

sp500_options[lag_BID_PRICE == 0 & BID_PRICE == 0, max_DOUBLE_ZERO_BID_PRICE := max(STRIKEPRICE), by = .(UNDERLYING, Time, MATURITYDATE, OPTIONTYPE)]

# replace NA's
sp500_options[, min_DOUBLE_ZERO_BID_PRICE := max(min_DOUBLE_ZERO_BID_PRICE, na.rm=T), by = .(UNDERLYING, Time, MATURITYDATE, OPTIONTYPE)]

sp500_options[, max_DOUBLE_ZERO_BID_PRICE := max(max_DOUBLE_ZERO_BID_PRICE, na.rm=T), by = .(UNDERLYING, Time, MATURITYDATE, OPTIONTYPE)]

sp500_options[min_DOUBLE_ZERO_BID_PRICE < 0, min_DOUBLE_ZERO_BID_PRICE := -1 * min_DOUBLE_ZERO_BID_PRICE]

sp500_options <- sp500_options[(OPTIONTYPE == "C" & STRIKEPRICE < min_DOUBLE_ZERO_BID_PRICE) | (OPTIONTYPE == "P" & STRIKEPRICE > max_DOUBLE_ZERO_BID_PRICE) ]

sp500_options <- sp500_options[BID_PRICE > 0]
```

How to deal with this??
[image]

Comment: You get `Inf` when there are only NA values and with `na.rm = TRUE`, it returns `Inf` `min(NA)#
[1] NA
> min(NA, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] Inf`  It is just a warning and not an error

Answer (score 0):

One option to deal is to check for `any` non-NA elements and then apply the function or `else` return the `NA`

```
library(data.table)
sp500_options[lag_BID_PRICE == 0 & BID_PRICE == 0,
    min_DOUBLE_ZERO_BID_PRICE := if(all(is.na(STRIKEPRICE))) NA_real_ 
     else min(STRIKEPRICE, na.rm = TRUE), 
             by = .(UNDERLYING, Time, MATURITYDATE, OPTIONTYPE)]
```

---

Or another option is using `fmin/fmax` from `collapse` which returns `NA` when all elements are NA or else return the min value by dropping the NAs

```
library(collapse)
> fmin(c(NA, NA, NA))
[1] NA
> fmin(c(NA, NA, NA, 3))
[1] 3
> fmin(c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 2))
[1] 2
```

Therefore, change the code to

```
sp500_options[lag_BID_PRICE == 0 & BID_PRICE == 0, 
    min_DOUBLE_ZERO_BID_PRICE := fmin(STRIKEPRICE), 
    by = .(UNDERLYING, Time, MATURITYDATE, OPTIONTYPE)]
```